# Find same name of text file like in the first column and print text if condition is true

Tags: if-statement, awk, conditional-statements

I have one text file and folder with another text files, delimited by tab. I would like to use condition if value smaller than 0 print specific text to another file with another condition.

For example:

1. file:

> ```
> 112   0.6
> 116  -0.3
> 198  -0.7
> 205   0.4
> ```

2. folder, where is 4 files with same name like in 1. file in first column.

> ```
> 112.tsv
> 116.tsv -here i would like to add last row with "This is the row what I want"
> 198.tsv -here i would like to add last row with "This is the row what I want"
> 205.tsv
> ```

I would like to use awk code:

```
awk '{if ($2<=0); print "This is the row what I want" "?? to file with same name like $1 ??"}' 1.file
```

Please could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (untested) will do it:

```
awk '$2<0 { print "This is the row what I want" >> ("folder/"$1".tsv") }' file
```

You MIGHT need to add a `;close("folder/"$1".tsv")` after the print if you aren't using GNU awk and can have a lot of files open simultaneously .